# How to render an <img> element within a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to render the return  from the else if statement.

Is there a way to have the images render within the  tags?

I would like to show a different image depending on the result returned from the API

```
export default function GetDieResult() {
  const [dieRollResult, setDieRollResult] = useState(1);
  
  const whichDieImageToDisply = (rollResult ) => {
    if (rollResult === 1) {
      return <img className="die" src={d1} alt="A die displaying 1" />;
    } else if (rollResult === 2) {
      return <img className="die" src={d2} alt="A die displaying 2" />;
    } else if (rollResult === 3) {
      return <img className="die" src={d3} alt="A die displaying 3" />;
    } else if (rollResult === 4) {
      return <img className="die" src={d4} alt="A die displaying 4" />;
    } else if (rollResult === 5) {
      return <img className="die" src={d5} alt="A die displaying 5" />;
    } else if (rollResult === 6) {
      return <img className="die" src={d6} alt="A die displaying 6" />;
    }
  };

  const checkResponse = (response) => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Network error: ${response.status}`);
    return response.json();
  };

  const rollDie = () => {
    fetch("https://rolz.org/api/?d6.json")
      .then(checkResponse)
      .then((data) => {
        setDieRollResult(data.result);
        whichDieImageToDisply();
        console.log(whichDieImageToDisply(data.result))
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    rollDie();
  }, [dieRollResult]);

  console.log(dieRollResult);

  return (
    <main>
    
      <img src={d1} alt="A die displaying 1" className="die" />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: `return
<main>
    {whichDieImageToDisply()}
 </main>` Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would do some refactoring on the code and simplify it a bit.

First, I would move the fetching to the `useEffect` hook and make the dependency array empty. This way it will only make the request to the API once after rendering the component. Then, I would create a `status` state so I can easier track in which status the component is currently at. This then allows me to render the correct image based on the `dieRollResult` that got fetched from the API. Also, you can simply call the `dieImage()` function in the `JSX` that will then render the correct image based on `dieRollResult` and because we are using `status` here, the `dieImage()` function will be called only when you have fetched the data from the API. Until then, it will show you a loading text.

```js
function GetDieResult() {
  const [dieRollResult, setDieRollResult] = useState(1);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("idle");

  const dieImage = () => {
    if (dieRollResult === 1) {
      return <img className="die" src={d1} alt="A die displaying 1" />;
    } else if (dieRollResult === 2) {
      return <img className="die" src={d2} alt="A die displaying 2" />;
    } else if (dieRollResult === 3) {
      return <img className="die" src={d3} alt="A die displaying 3" />;
    } else if (dieRollResult === 4) {
      return <img className="die" src={d4} alt="A die displaying 4" />;
    } else if (dieRollResult === 5) {
      return <img className="die" src={d5} alt="A die displaying 5" />;
    } else if (dieRollResult === 6) {
      return <img className="die" src={d6} alt="A die displaying 6" />;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setStatus("fetching");

    fetch("https://rolz.org/api/?d6.json").then(async (res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        setStatus("failed");

        throw new Error(`Network error: ${res.status}`);
      }

      const { result } = await res.json();

      setDieRollResult(result);
      setStatus("processed");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      {status === "processed" ? (
        dieImage()
      ) : (
        <p style={{ color: "blue" }}>loading...</p>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: could I add a button to this to run ```GetDieResult()``` on click? EG ```<button
        onClick={GetDieResult()}>Click to roll</button>```

Comment: Yes you could, try it and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You can call function from return block. `whichDieImageToDisply()` .But if that function needs to take state, or needs to be defined inside component, and every render will create function again. You might need to wrap it with useCallback etc; but i will provide an alternative way, i think better and cleaner way, via enums.

Inside your return block you can use this; you wont need a whichDieImageToDisply function.

```
  {
    {
      1: <img className="die" src={d1} alt="A die displaying 1" />;,
      2: <img className="die" src={d2} alt="A die displaying 2" />,
      3: <img className="die" src={d3} alt="A die displaying 3" />,
      4: <img className="die" src={d4} alt="A die displaying 4" />;,
      5: <img className="die" src={d5} alt="A die displaying 5" />,
      6: <img className="die" src={d6} alt="A die displaying 6" />,
    }[dieRollResult]
  }
```

More: https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Img (props) {

  const [myPic, setMyPic] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(props.url)
      .then(res=>res.blob())
      .then(pic =>{
         const auxUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pic);
         setMyPic(auxUrl);

         return function () {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(auxUrl);
         }
      })
  }, [props.url]);

  return (
    <img src={myPic} />
  )
}
```